# phpmyadmin unable to login

Tags: password, phpmyadmin, 500-error

Over the past couple of days I have usually not been able to login to phpMyadmin, but once I was able to. Either I  get a blank screen of this message: This page isn’t working xx.xxx.xxx.xxx is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500. (this happens in Chrome, Firefox, Edge)

I am just setting up Wordpress thru Google Deployment (what a pain) and this is my first time using the phpMyAdmin. The original problem is a plugin which broke the site after activation. I know of no other way to get to the plugin to disable it.

Comment: Read the error logs of your webserver

Comment: Plugin? A wordpress plugin? If so then that has nothing to do with PHPMyAdmin - one post, one question, please. (you might try wpcli for that issue)

Answer (score 0):

In such cases, the best thing to do is check your web server's error logs and check the exact error. This issue can happen if there's an error in your plugin's code, Apache's `.htaccess` file or similar. If you know that it's caused by a particular plugin and wants to disable it, there are a couple of ways to do so. One of them is to

1. Go to `wp-contents/plugins/<plugins_folder>` and rename/delete the plugin's folder.
2. If you have access to the databaes, you can also make changes to the `wp_options` table to disable it, more details regarding this is mentioned [here](https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/disable-wordpress-plugins/#step-3-open-options-table).